# How to send byte[] to BLE device without a custom UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin-studio

I am trying to send a byte array from a 6.0.1 android device to a RN4020 bluetooth module. So far I have been able to discover, bond with, and connect to the module. I am trying to send the byte array using the built in 16 bit UUID for writing without response. When I use my code I don't get any errors, the byte array just doesn't get sent. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
namespace Remote
{
    [Activity(Label = "Remote", MainLauncher = true, Icon =     "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        const string UniversalUUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
        const string MAC = "00:1E:C0:22:3D:0E";
        ICollection<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
        BluetoothAdapter adapter;
        BluetoothDevice device;
        BluetoothGatt gatt;
        BluetoothGattCallback callBack;
        BluetoothManager manager;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button test = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Test);
            EditText MACs = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.MACs);

            pairedDevices = getAllPairedDevices();

            test.Click += delegate
            {
                    connected();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte [] { 124, 079, 044, 048, 052, 044, 048, 052, 013, 010};//stringToByteArray("|O,04,04\r");
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new     BluetoothGattCharacteristic(UUID.NameUUIDFromBytes(new byte[] { 0, 4}),     GattProperty.Write, GattPermission.Write);
                    characteristic.SetValue(buffer);
                    gatt.WriteCharacteristic(characteristic);
             };


        private ICollection<BluetoothDevice> getAllPairedDevices()
        {
            BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
            return btAdapter.BondedDevices;
        }

        private async Task<bool> connected()
        {
            manager =     (BluetoothManager)GetSystemService(Context.BluetoothService);
            adapter = manager.Adapter;
            device = adapter.GetRemoteDevice(MAC);
            gatt = device.ConnectGatt(this, false, callBack);    

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the constructor for BluetoothGattCharacteristic is public. The correct way to obtain a BluetoothGattCharacteristic is to do a service discovery, by calling gatt.DiscoverServices(). When you get the callback that the service discovery is done, you can obtain all the services and characteristics by gatt.GetServices().

In your code you also don't wait until you are connected. The device.ConnectGatt method is asynchronous meaning that it starts a connection attempt. Your callback object's OnConnectionStateChange will be called when your device connects/disconnects.

Comment: 1 I don't know how to get the callback to start a method execution on a success event - an example would be much appreciated.

2 I seem to be missing a gatt.GetServices() method all I have is a gatt.getService(UUID)

Comment: I am pretty new to bluetooth and xamarin in general and have been scouring the internet for a week and I haven't found any xamarin examples of how to do this. At this point I am pretty desperate. So can someone please give a sample code of how to send a byte array to a UUID including the connection procedure. please

Comment: Any Java example would work. It's the same APIs in the Xamarin dialect. For example check out https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/cefd49aae65dc85161d08419494071d74ffb982f/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com/example/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeService.java.